# ASP.NET MVC 2 List<T> model validation

Tags: .net, validation, asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations, asp.net-mvc-validation

I am working on MVC 2 application and I have a problem. My code looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Users()
        {
            try
            {
                var model = new List<User>
                                {
                                    new User
                                        {
                                            Name = "Test",
                                            UserID = 1,
                                            Salary = 1000m
                                        }
                                };
                return View(model);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Log exception
                return View("ErrorPage");
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Users(IEnumerable<User> users)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

                return View(users);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Log exception
                return View("ErrorPage");
            }
        }
```

and class User

```
public class User
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name{ get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int UserID{ get; set; }

        [Required]
        public decimal Salary{ get; set; }
    }
```

I want to create custom attribute (DataAnnototation) to validate if sum of salaries in IEnumerable users upon posting the form is less than 10000? Can I do it here, cause my model is List?

Comment: Don't swallow exceptions

Answer (score 1):

Data Annotations cannot operate across a collection.

Instead, you need to validate that manually in the action.

You can then call `ModelState.AddModelError()`.